# Why mongo aggregate works in the shell but exceeds 16MB in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm having a quite huge mongo aggregate command.

```
db.container_product.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$product"},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$product","container_ids":{"$push":"$container_id"}}}
])
```

It results in almost 5k groups, but they're all plain integers. For example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(107058402), 
    "container_ids" : [
        NumberInt(107058409), 
        NumberInt(107058410), 
        NumberInt(107058411), 
        NumberInt(107058412), 
        NumberInt(107058413)
    ]
}
```

And it works just fine when I run it in the shell (plain shell, but also  Robomongo etc.). But when I try to run it from the PHP it gives me 16MB error.

`172.16.0.2:27017: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`

What's the huge difference between PHP and shell in this case?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell uses a js wrapper for the [aggregate command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate), which implicitly uses [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#cursor-behavior), so it can return result of any size (the limit of 16 MB per document still applies). You can see the source code of the wrapper by calling `db.collection.aggregate` in the shell.

In PHP [MongoCollection::aggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) calls the command directly to return a single document, not a cursor. You need to use [MongoCollection::aggregateCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregatecursor.php) instead.